# Create string from variable name and run through recursive function

Tags: r, function

I have a list of dataframes:

```
frame_list = lst(NotREP, Day0_4, Day10_12, Day14_15, Day20, Day5_7, OIS)
```

And I want to create folders for each dataframe, each with the name of the dataframe (and then put things in these folders based on additional analysis in the same function, so I cannot just use sapply). I have created the (simplified) function:

```
Create_dir = function(data){
  filename = deparse(substitute(data))
  dir.create(filename, showWarnings = FALSE)
}
```

and used the for loop

```
for(i in frame_list){
  Create_dir(i)
}
```

But this names all the folders "i". Is there a way I could run the list of dataframes through the `Create_dir` function and give the folders their proper names?

Alternatively, I can name the dataframes in framelist:

```
names(Filter_list) = c("NotREP", "Day0_4", "Day10_12", "Day14_15", "Day20", 
    "Day5_7", "OIS")
```

But I do not know how to get the for loop to recognise the name[i]. I have tried

```
for(i in Filter_list) {
  foldername = names(Filter_list)[[i]]
  Create_dir(foldername)
  }
```

And various similar things, but can't get the `for` function to recognise the names.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `Create_dir(paste0(i))`.

Comment: @Nico I think that will just name all the directories `"paste0(i)"`

Comment: You could change the line `filename = deparse(substitute(data))` to `filename = eval(substitute(data))`

Comment: Yeah, just names the folder paste0(i) (@Nico)

Comment: @James what output do you get if you run your version of `frame_list` through my `Create_dir2` function below?

Comment: @Allan, tried and get: Error in dir.create(filename, showWarnings = FALSE) : 
  invalid 'path' argument

Comment: @James the problem you have is that `frame_list` contains _unnamed_ copies of your data frames, so once you create `frame_list` there aren't any names in it you can use to create the file path. There are lots of other ways to do this, of course: you can make frame_list a named list, or you can write a function that takes all the data frames you want to put in `frame_list`, but you can't do it the way you are trying to.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Allan, I will name the list and adapt my procedure then. That's very helpful cheers! :)

Comment: In that case: Sorry. But the answer below looks promising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reprex to show that you should use `eval` instead of `deparse` when using your function in a loop:

```r
frame_list <- list("Hello", "World")

Create_dir1 = function(data) print(deparse(substitute(data)))

Create_dir2 <- function(data) print(eval(substitute(data)))

for(i in frame_list) Create_dir1(i)
#> [1] "i"
#> [1] "i"

for(i in frame_list) Create_dir2(i)
#> [1] "Hello"
#> [1] "World"
```

---

### **Update**

Based on further information from the OP, we don't need non-standard evaluation at all since the names can be passed directly to `dir.create` without the `Create_dir` function:

```
names(Filter_list) <- c("NotREP", "Day0_4", "Day10_12", "Day14_15", "Day20", 
    "Day5_7", "OIS")

for(i in names(Filter_list)){
   dir.create(i, showWarnings = FALSE)
   dosomethingwith(Filter_list[[i]])
}
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Allan, I have updated my question after attempting to create a named list, but I am still struggling.

Comment: @James see my update. Maybe we were making things too complicated?

Comment: yes that works fine on its own. The problem is that I need it to access both the name to create the folder, and then the dataframe itself to do other functions such as write.csv. So Create_dir needs to run names[i] and [i]

Comment: Yes, but @James you can access the data frames now with  `Filter_list[[i]]` - that was the point. See my update

Comment: Allan, thank you so much. This is going to be tricky but I think I can make this work. Sorry for delayed reply.